# Regular Expression for Number Less Then 60

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression for any number from 1-60, here's what I have so far:

`[0-6][0-9]`

Super simple. When I input a number like 950, it catches the 50, ignores a 9 is in front.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `^[1-6]?[0-9]$` or `\b[0-6][0-9]\b`

Comment: Are negative numbers possible? i.e. Would `-1` potentially show up? I assume you don't want to match those. Also, which language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\b([1-9]|[1-5]\d|60)\b
```

You have to encapsulate it in word breaks (`\b`) to ensure parts of a number aren't matched (like 950).

---

The idea is to either match a single digit number - 1 to 9 inclusive (`[1-9]`), or (`|`) a two digit number, where the first digit is between 1 and 5 inclusive (`[1-5]\d`), or `60` itself.

Comment: Matches `0`, which is out of range.

Comment: `(?<!\S)(?:[1-9]|[1-5]\d|60)(?!\S)` may be used assuming lookbehinds and lookaheads are supported if they don't want to match `-1` or similar